# String para Date

Tags: javascript, string, data, conversão

Estou criando alguns `parsers` e estava fazendo uns testes para desenvolver o de Date.

Este código:

```
value = '2015-12-31 23:16:00'
value = value.replace(/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}) ?(\d{2}:\d{2})?(:\d{2})?.*/, '$1T$2$3');
value = value.replace(/T$/, '');
value = value.replace(/(:\d{2})$/, '$1Z');

value = new Date(value)
```

executa corretamente no Firefox, retornando `Date 2015-12-31T23:16:00.000Z`, contudo no Chrome ele exibe `Thu Dec 31 2015 21:16:00 GMT-0200 (BRST)`

Além de estarem exibindo diferente, o Chrome abateu duas horas do horário original.

Alguém saberia como posso revolver isto?

Comment: sem o 'Z' funcionou corretamente aqui no meu `Chrome`, talvez te oriente em algo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109894/new-date-works-differently-in-chrome-and-firefox

Comment: @MaiconCarraro na verdade eu já tinha encontrado esta referencia, do `Z` no final, e estou aplicando ela, se você comentar a minha que tem `value = new Date(value)` o valor exibido no console sera, `"2015-12-31T23:16:00Z"`, contudo ainda permanece uma diferença de duas horas no `Chrome`

Comment: Pelos meus testes não ha problema na hora, é apenas sua exibição que é divergente nos navegadores. Em ambos executando o `getUTCHours()`, me retornou `23`. Assim como nas demais funções.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como o @Guilherme Lautert disse no comentário, nos dois casos retorna o mesmo valor, apenas apresentando-o de forma diferente. O que muda é apenas o fuso horário que foi usado, sendo que GMT-0200 indica duas horas a menos do que a hora atual no meridiano de Greenwich. Exemplo: http://www.donathan.com/dave/m0200.html.

Tente usar

```
var horarioAtual = date.toLocaleTimeString();
```

para verificar. É provável que irá retornar o valor correto nos dois casos.