# new Date() sem fuso horário

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Tenho que enviar uma **data** javascript para o meu *controller* através do `FullCalendar`. Na minha action, estou recebendo um `DateTime` e preciso enviar através do arquivo javascript com o `new Date(minha_variavel)`.

Porém quando faço isso, ele vêm com o fuso horário de *-3 horas*, ou seja se eu seleciono dia **10/08/2015 00:00:00** no `FullCalendar`, eu recebo no *controller* a seguinte data: **09/08/2015 21:00:00**.

Tem algum jeito de passar data sem que aconteça isso?

Comment: Ele pode estar usando o GMT. Tente alterar para UTC ou alterar seu time zone no OS, acho que poderia dar certo.

Comment: essa  página da documentação pode ajudar: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/timezone/timezone/

Comment: tlz ajude http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72294/string-para-date [errei o link]

Comment: Você já pensou em usar a momentjs pra gerenciar isso?

Answer (score 2):

quando for trabalhar com datas a melhor alternativa é trabalhar com [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)

mas voce poderia utilizar:

```
var d = new Date('10/08/2015 00:00:00');
d.toLocaleString() // 08/10/2015 00:00:00
d.toString(); //Thu Oct 08 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)
d.toGMTString();  //Thu, 08 Oct 2015 03:00:00 GMT
d.toUTCString();  //Thu, 08 Oct 2015 03:00:00 GMT
```